# Why is this function being called with an object if I am passing it just a primitive value?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am learning react-testing-library.

I have this component called MovieForm, it has an onSubmit handler that is mapped to a function coming from props that are called submit form. The `onSubmit` is called with a state property called `text`

This is how the component looks:

```
export default class MovieForm extends Component {

  state = {
    text: 'x',
  }

  render() {

    const {submitForm} = this.props
    const {text} = this.state
    debugger
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={() => submitForm({text})} data-testid="movie-form">
          <input onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} type="text" name="" id=""/>
          <h1>text: {text}</h1>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then in my test i am mocking that `onSubmit` with `jest.fn()`

But when I test if the `submitForm` was called with 'x, as that is what the initial state of `state.text` was, it throws an error and says it was actually called with `{"text": "x"}`

ERROR:

```
  Expected mock function to have been called with:
      ["x"]
    But it was called with:
      [{"text": "x"}]
```

I don't understand why it says it was called as an object if it was passed just the value of text not the object:

```
   <form onSubmit={() => submitForm({text})} data-testid="movie-form">
```

Can you explain why this is so?

This is the test:

```
const onSubmit = jest.fn()

test('<MovieForm />', () => {
  const {debug, getByTestId, queryByTestId, container, getByText} = render(<MovieForm submitForm= {onSubmit} />)
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Submit'))
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('x')
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually passing an object to `onSubmit`:

```
<form onSubmit={() => submitForm({text})} data-testid="movie-form">
```

`{text}` is an object.

Instead, change to pass `text` instead of `{text}`:

```
<form onSubmit={() => submitForm(text)} data-testid="movie-form">
```

Hope this helps.